Seeking Implement a PE Parsing Tool for MFC DLLs - Encountering Issues with Loading Various Tables
I am currently working on developing my own PE
parsing tool, specifically aimed at recursively loading MFC
DLLs. While I have successfully implemented loading for several components such as the relocation table, TLS
, and the import table, I am running into some challenges when it comes to loading other sections of the PE file, including the resource table.
Here’s a brief overview of what I have accomplished so far:
I can successfully load the relocation table and apply the necessary relocations.
I have implemented TLS loading and can access and use the thread-local variables.
I can parse and load the import table, allowing me to resolve dependencies.
    struct ThreadInitializer {
        static DWORD mainThreadId;
    };
    static ThreadInitializer initializer;
    DWORD ThreadInitializer::mainThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    class MemoryPE {
        std::string& fileName;
        LPVOID fileImage;
        DWORD fileSize;
        PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER m_pDosHeader;
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS m_pNtHeader;
        PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER m_pSectionHeader;
        void* m_VirtualAddress;
        INLINE unsigned int GetAlignedSize(unsigned int iOriginalData, unsigned int Alignment) //iOriginalData原始数据 iAlignment对齐边界
        {
            if (Alignment & (Alignment - 1)) return -1;
            return (iOriginalData + Alignment - 1) & ~(Alignment - 1);
        }
    public:
        MemoryPE(std::string _fileName, LPVOID _fileImage, DWORD _fileSize) :fileName(_fileName), fileImage(_fileImage), fileSize(_fileSize) {
            m_pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)fileImage;
            m_pNtHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS) & ((const unsigned char*)(fileImage))[m_pDosHeader->e_lfanew];
            m_pSectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((PBYTE)m_pNtHeader + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
        }
        ~MemoryPE() {}
        INLINE int GetVirtualSize() {
            int MemoryAlign = m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;   
            auto sectionsum = GetAlignedSize(m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, MemoryAlign);
            auto pSectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((PBYTE)m_pNtHeader + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
            for (int i = 0; i < m_pNtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; ++i) {
                int iTureCodeSize = pSectionHeader[i].Misc.VirtualSize;     
                int iFileAlignCodeSize = pSectionHeader[i].SizeOfRawData;  
                int iMaxSize = (iFileAlignCodeSize > iTureCodeSize) ? (iFileAlignCodeSize) : (iTureCodeSize);
                int iSectionSize = GetAlignedSize(pSectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress + iMaxSize, MemoryAlign);
                if (sectionsum < (unsigned int)iSectionSize) {
                    sectionsum = iSectionSize;   //Use the Max
                }
            }
            return sectionsum;
        }
        bool Run() {
            AUTOLOG
            auto& lasterror = LastError::GetInstance();
            lasterror = ERROR_SUCCESS;
            if (!IsDosHeaderValid()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_DLL_MIGHT_BE_INCOMPATIBLE;
                std::cerr << "Dos header is not valid." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!IsNtHeaderValid()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_DLL_MIGHT_BE_INCOMPATIBLE;
                std::cerr << "Nt header is not valid." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!IsDllFileFormat()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_DLL_MIGHT_BE_INCOMPATIBLE;
                std::cerr << "File is not a DLL." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!IsOptionalHeaderSizeCorrect()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_INCORRECT_SIZE;
                std::cerr << "Optional header size is incorrect." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!HasExports()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_DLL_MIGHT_BE_INCOMPATIBLE;
                std::cerr << "No exports found." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!AllocateVirtualMemory()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
                std::cerr << "Failed to allocate virtual memory." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!CopyDataSections()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_DLL_MIGHT_BE_INCOMPATIBLE;
                std::cerr << "Failed to copy data sections." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!FixImportTable()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_DLL_MIGHT_BE_INCOMPATIBLE;
                std::cerr << "Failed to fix import table." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!FixRelocationTable()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_ILLEGAL_DLL_RELOCATION;
                std::cerr << "Failed to fix relocation table." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!FixTLSTable()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_DLL_MIGHT_BE_INCOMPATIBLE;
                std::cerr << "Failed to fix TLS table." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!Flush()) {
                lasterror = ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS;
                std::cerr << "Failed to flush instruction cache." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            if (!ExecuteDLLMain()) {
                FreeVirtualMemory();//m_VirtualAddress = nullptr;
                lasterror = ERROR_BAD_DLL_ENTRYPOINT;
                std::cerr << "Failed to execute DLLMain." << std::endl;
                return lasterror;
            }
            return lasterror;
        }
        DWORD RvaToOffset(DWORD rva, IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER* sections, int numberOfSections) {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
                if (rva >= sections[i].VirtualAddress && rva < sections[i].VirtualAddress + sections[i].SizeOfRawData) {
                    return rva - sections[i].VirtualAddress + sections[i].PointerToRawData;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        INLINE bool IsDosHeaderValid() {
            AUTOLOG
            if (m_pDosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE) {
                return false;
            }
            if (m_pDosHeader->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        INLINE bool IsNtHeaderValid() {
            AUTOLOG
            if (m_pNtHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE) {
                return false;
            }
            if (m_pNtHeader->FileHeader.Machine != HOST_MACHINE) {
                return false;
            }
            if ((m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment & 1)!=0) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        INLINE bool IsDllFileFormat() {
            AUTOLOG
            if ((m_pNtHeader->FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_DLL) == 0)return false;
            return true;
        }
        INLINE bool IsExecutableImage() {
            AUTOLOG
            if ((m_pNtHeader->FileHeader.Characteristics & IMAGE_FILE_EXECUTABLE_IMAGE) == 0)return false;
            return true;
        }
        INLINE bool IsOptionalHeaderSizeCorrect() {
            AUTOLOG
            if (m_pNtHeader->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader != sizeof(IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER)){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        INLINE void* AllocateVirtualMemory() {
            AUTOLOG
            auto ImageLength = GetVirtualSize();
            m_VirtualAddress= VirtualAlloc(NULL, ImageLength, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
            return m_VirtualAddress;
        }
        INLINE bool FreeVirtualMemory() {
            AUTOLOG
            if (m_VirtualAddress) {
                VirtualFree(m_VirtualAddress, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
                m_VirtualAddress = nullptr;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        INLINE BOOL FixImportTable() {
            AUTOLOG
            ULONG ulOffset = m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress;
            if (!CheckHeader(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT))return TRUE;
            auto ImageImportDescriptor = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + ulOffset);
            std::stack<std::string> dllnames;
            
            while (ImageImportDescriptor->Characteristics != 0) {
                std::string szDllName((char*)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + ImageImportDescriptor->Name));
                if (!szDllName.empty())dllnames.push(szDllName);
                ImageImportDescriptor++;
            }
            
            while (!dllnames.empty()) {
                std::string dllname = dllnames.top();
                dllnames.pop();
                if (dllname.empty())continue;
                
                ImageImportDescriptor = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + ulOffset);
                while (ImageImportDescriptor->Characteristics != 0) {
                    std::string currentDllName((char*)((PBYTE)
                        m_VirtualAddress + ImageImportDescriptor->Name));
                    if (currentDllName == dllname)break;
                    ImageImportDescriptor++;
                }
                if (ImageImportDescriptor->Characteristics == 0)return FALSE; 
                auto hDll = GetModuleHandleA(dllname.c_str());
                if (hDll == NULL)hDll = LoadLibraryA(dllname.c_str());
                if (!hDll) return false;
                
                auto FirstThunkData = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + ImageImportDescriptor->FirstThunk);
                auto OriginalThunkData = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + ImageImportDescriptor->OriginalFirstThunk);
                for (int i = 0;; i++) {
                    if (OriginalThunkData[i].u1.Function == 0)break;
                    FARPROC FunctionAddress = NULL;
                    
                    if (OriginalThunkData[i].u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG) {
                        
                        DWORD ordinal = OriginalThunkData[i].u1.Ordinal & ~IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG;
                        FunctionAddress = GetProcAddress(hDll, (char*)ordinal);
                    }else {
                        
                        auto ImageImportByName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + OriginalThunkData[i].u1.AddressOfData);
                        FunctionAddress = GetProcAddress(hDll, (char*)ImageImportByName->Name);
                    }
                    
                    if (FunctionAddress != NULL) {
#ifdef _WIN64
                        FirstThunkData[i].u1.Function = (ULONGLONG)FunctionAddress;
#else
                        FirstThunkData[i].u1.Function = (DWORD)FunctionAddress;
#endif
                    }else {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                }
            }
            LastError::GetInstance()=ERROR_SUCCESS;
            return TRUE;
        }
        


        INLINE bool FixRelocationTable(){
            AUTOLOG
            if (!CheckHeader(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC)) return true;
            
            auto BaseRelocation = (PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)((ULONG_PTR)m_VirtualAddress +
                m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress);
            if (!BaseRelocation) return false;
            while ((BaseRelocation->VirtualAddress + BaseRelocation->SizeOfBlock) != 0){
                auto RelocationData = (WORD*)((PBYTE)BaseRelocation + sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION));
                
                int NumberOfRelocation = (BaseRelocation->SizeOfBlock - sizeof(IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)) / sizeof(WORD);
                for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfRelocation; i++)
                {
                    
                    if ((DWORD)(RelocationData[i] & 0xF000) == 0x0000A000){
                        
#ifdef _WIN64
                        auto Address = (ULONGLONG*)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + BaseRelocation->VirtualAddress + (RelocationData[i] & 0x0FFF));
                        auto  ulDelta = (ULONGLONG)m_VirtualAddress - m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
                        *Address += ulDelta;
#endif
                    }else if ((DWORD)(RelocationData[i] & 0xF000) == 0x00003000){
                        
#ifndef _WIN64
                        DWORD* Address = (DWORD*)((PBYTE)ImageData + BaseRelocation->VirtualAddress + (RelocationData[i] & 0x0FFF));
                        DWORD  dwDelta = (DWORD)ImageData - m_NtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
                        *Address += dwDelta;
#endif
                    }
                }
                
                BaseRelocation = (PIMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION)((PBYTE)BaseRelocation + BaseRelocation->SizeOfBlock);
            }
            return true;
        }
        INLINE bool CopyDataSections(){
            AUTOLOG
            
            int HeaderLength = m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders;
        
            if(!HeaderLength) return false;
            if (!m_VirtualAddress)  return false;
            memcpy(m_VirtualAddress, fileImage, HeaderLength);
            
            for (int i = 0; i < m_pNtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; ++i){
                if (m_pSectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress == 0 || m_pSectionHeader[i].SizeOfRawData == 0)continue;
                
                auto SectionMemoryAddress = (VOID*)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + m_pSectionHeader[i].VirtualAddress);
                
                memcpy((VOID*)SectionMemoryAddress, (VOID*)((PBYTE)fileImage + m_pSectionHeader[i].PointerToRawData),
                    m_pSectionHeader[i].SizeOfRawData);
            }
            
            m_pDosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)m_VirtualAddress;
            
            m_pNtHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + (m_pDosHeader->e_lfanew));
            
            m_pSectionHeader = (PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)((PBYTE)m_pNtHeader + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));
            return true;
        }
        INLINE bool Flush() {
            AUTOLOG
            ULONG ulOld;
            if (m_VirtualAddress) {
                VirtualProtect(m_VirtualAddress, GetVirtualSize(), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &ulOld);
                FlushInstructionCache(GetCurrentProcess(), m_VirtualAddress, GetVirtualSize());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        INLINE bool FixTLSTable() {
            AUTOLOG
            auto TLSdirectory = (PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY) & (m_pNtHeader)->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_TLS];
            if (!CheckHeader(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_TLS)) return true;
            auto tlsAddr = (PIMAGE_TLS_DIRECTORY)((PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress + TLSdirectory->VirtualAddress);
            auto callback = (PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK*)tlsAddr->AddressOfCallBacks;
            if (callback) {
                while (*callback) {
                    (*callback)(m_VirtualAddress, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, NULL);
                    callback++;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        
        BOOL UpdateImageBase(){
            AUTOLOG
            m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase = (ULONG_PTR)m_VirtualAddress;
            return TRUE;
        }
        PIMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY GetHeader(DWORD dwindex) {
            return &m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[dwindex];
        }
        bool CheckHeader(DWORD nIndex) {
            AUTOLOG
            auto exportDir = GetHeader(nIndex);
            return !(exportDir->Size == 0 || exportDir->VirtualAddress == 0);
        }
        bool HasExports() {
            AUTOLOG
            return CheckHeader(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT);
        }
        
        INLINE bool ExecuteDLLMain() {
            AUTOLOG
            typedef   BOOL(*ProcDllMain)(HINSTANCE, DWORD, LPVOID);
            auto pDllMain = (ProcDllMain)(m_pNtHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint + (PBYTE)m_VirtualAddress);
            if (pDllMain&&IsExecutableImage()) {
                auto ExcuteDll = [=]()->bool     {
                    if (pDllMain((HINSTANCE)m_VirtualAddress, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0) == FALSE) {
                        pDllMain((HINSTANCE)m_VirtualAddress, DLL_PROCESS_DETACH, 0);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                };
                if (GetCurrentThreadId() != ThreadInitializer::mainThreadId) {
                     return ExcuteDll();
                }else {
                    std::thread(ExcuteDll).detach();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        INLINE HMODULE GetModuleInstance() {
            AUTOLOG
            return (HMODULE)m_VirtualAddress;
        }
        
    };

How do I access and read the resource table? I understand it is structured differently from the relocation and import tables, but I'm having trouble figuring out its layout.
Are there any specific steps or considerations to keep in mind when recursively loading resources in MFC DLLs?
Could you provide any examples or references to resources regarding the structure of the resource table or how to handle the various types of resources?

Asking for external resources is off-topic for StackOverflow. What are you having trouble with? What have you attempted so far that is not working for you? That said, have a look at the "The Resources Section" portion of An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format, Part 2 (archive)

The .rsrc Section
